# Numpy vectorize excluded argument

Tags: numpy, vectorization

Please I need someone to explain  the function of excluded argument in Numpy vectorize function in a simple way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Sounds like you are a `numpy` beginner.  I don't think you should be spending much time learning `np.vectorize`.  I have answered a few questions involving this `excluded` parameter, but explaining it without a clear sense of how much you know, or what you need, probably isn't worth our time.

Comment: I have knowledge of some of the functions.I just don't understand what was meant by 'the value passed to the excluded keyword will not be vectorized. Please just  explain a bit. Thanks for the previous reply too

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes you don't want all of your objects to be iterated. Two examples:

in your function `f(a,b)` is for single elements like `np.mod(a,b)`. No problem vectorizing here:

```
import numpy as np

vc = np.vectorize(np.mod)
print(vc([5,11,7,4],2)) # first element will be iterated
print(vc([5,11,7,4],[2,3,4,5])) # both elements will be iterated
print(vc(5,[2,3,4,5])) # only second element will be iterated
```

on the other hand you have a function `g(x,p)` which requires an array for `p` (example: a lookup table or parameters for a polynom). Therefore `p` has to stay an array, otherwhise the function would give an error or false data. This is done by excluding `p`. Please note that by using exclude, all your parameters now have to be named. Example:

```
import numpy as np

def g(x,p):
  return p[0]+x*p[1]+x*x*p[2]

print(g(5,[0,0,1]))

vg = np.vectorize(g, excluded=['p'])
print(vg(x=[0,1,2,3,4,5],p=[0,0,1])) # p will not be iterated
```